# Label não some Django

Tags: javascript, django-2.0

Uso um radio e um script em JavaScript para fazer a ação de sumir o campo agência do Model relatório, o problema é que some apenas o combobox o label não some.

Model

```
class Relatorio(models.Model):
    data_inicial = models.DateField(default=timezone.now)
    data_final = models.DateField(default=timezone.now)
    tipo = models.CharField(max_length=30, choices = TIPOS, default='ENVIO')
    usuario = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    agencia = models.ForeignKey(Group, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
```

JavaScript

```
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $('input[type="radio"]').change(function(){    
        if ($(this).is('#id_tipo_1')){
             $('#id_agencia, label[for="#id_agencia"]').parent().hide()     

         }else{
             $('#id_agencia, [for="#id_agencia"]').parent().show()

         }
   });
});
</script>
```

Demonstração:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seu erro é que você está colocando o símbolo `#` no seletor do label, e desta forma o seletor não acha o elemento:

```
[for="#id_agencia"]
      ↑
```

Quando deveria ser apenas:

```
[for="id_agencia"]
```

Também não precisa incluir `label` no seletor, basta assim:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
   $('input[type="radio"]').change(function(){    
      if ($(this).is('#id_tipo_1')){
         $('#id_agencia, [for="id_agencia"]').parent().hide()     
      }else{
         $('#id_agencia, [for="id_agencia"]').parent().show()
      }
   });
});
```

Um exemplo:

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
   $('input[type="radio"]').change(function(){    
      if ($(this).is('#id_tipo_1')){
         $('#id_agencia, [for="id_agencia"]').parent().hide()     
      }else{
         $('#id_agencia, [for="id_agencia"]').parent().show()
      }
   });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="radio" name="rad" id="id_tipo_2" checked>Envio
<input type="radio" name="rad" id="id_tipo_1">Recebimento
<br>
<table>
   <tr>
      <td>
         <label for="id_agencia">Agência</label>
      </td>
      <td>
         <select id="id_agencia">
            <option>------</option>
         </select>
      </td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Valeu me ajudou muito!